# How to work with Geometry from AMFLoader in THREE.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using STLLoader and AMFLoader to load models in a scene.  When the file is an STL file, I load the file and calculate the bounding box along with my own functions for calculating the volume and surface area:

```
        var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
    loader.load('file.stl'', function ( geometry ) {

        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xeaeaea/*, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 100*/ } );
        geometry.computeBoundingBox(geometry);
        bBox = geometry.boundingBox;
        geometry.computeVertexNormals();

        // convert buffergeometry to geometry so attributes can be used to calculate volume and area
        var calcGeometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry(geometry);
        // calculate Volume
        modelVolume = calculateVolume(calcGeometry);
        // calculate Surface Area
        modelArea = calculateArea(calcGeometry);

        meshMain = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

        meshMain.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
        meshMain.rotation.set( 0, - Math.PI / 2, 0 );
        meshMain.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );

        // center the rotational pivot point on center of geometry
        meshMain.translation = geometry.center();

        // bounding box info
        showBoundingBox = new THREE.BoxHelper(meshMain, bBoxColor);

        meshMain.castShadow = true;
        meshMain.receiveShadow = true;

        scene.add( meshMain );

    });
```

However, it seems that the AMFLoader returns the Mesh.  How do I work with the geometry of the returned mesh?  This is what I've tried:

```
        var loader = new THREE.AMFLoader();
    loader.load( 'file.amf', function ( amfobject ) {
        console.log(amfobject.geometry); // undefined

        scene.add( amfobject );
    } );
```

**EDIT**

This is what I am attempting to do:

```
        amfobject.children.forEach(function (child) {
            child.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
            child.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
            child.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
        });
```

but it says that child.geometry is undefined.

Comment: Try `console.log(amfobject)` and see what type it has. Possibly, it will be `THREE.Group()` and have the `children` property of an array of `THREE.Mesh()`

Comment: yes, it is a group.  However I tried this and the `amfobject.children.geometry` is undefined.

Comment: I found it.  it seems my particular model on has 1 child and the geometry is located here: `amfobject.children[0].children[0].geometry`